# Passing authenticated WIF session from Web App A to Web App B via Ajax call

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api2, restful-authentication, wif

The title is a little confusing because this is hard to explain.  So to start I'll go into a little more detail on the problem.

So I have a Rest API on Web Api 2 that authenticates currently via Microsoft Identity Model 3.5 consuming a FedAuth cookie.  This fed auth cookie is issued by the SessionAuthenticationModule on another web app.  That web app authenticates against ADFS and generates an authentication cookie.  I intended for that cookie to be on the root path and be on the same domain as the Rest API on web app 2.

As such, with "pass credentials true" on the ajax call, and the domain set on the cookie and both apps on the same base domain the authentication cookie is visible by the rest api and it's session authentication module consumes it and the rest api is authenticated as the logged in user on web app 1.

The issue is that due to issues out of my control, we are unable to change the Cookie path to be on the root path.  As such the cookie is not passed to the rest api.

So I need to come up with a solution to authenticate the rest api from the parent web apps authentication context.  I've come up with a few ideas:

1. Hook into Write Session Token, and generate a second cookie specifically for the API's that is on the root path with a new cookie name, but I don't really want to double the authentication payload on the web requests (double the cookies...)
2. Just do some basic rijandael encryption and encrypt the logged in user id in a new cookie and consume that and write an authorization filter on that in the rest api to authenticate if that cookie decrypts to a valid user id (with some salt).  The api only needs to know who the logged in user id is...
3. Set the fed auth cookie to be viewable in script (it's encrypted and we use cors), and then I can pass the cookie chunks in the ajax calls to the rest api as I can read them with js.
4. ???

Comment: For now I have written my own CookieAuth handler that hooks into OnAuthenticate and writes a new authentication cookie for my API, and my API has an IAuthenticationFilter that consumes that cookie and generates the current requests Principal Context.  This is working fine and is kind of neat.  I just wonder if there is a more official way of doing this.  I'm using Rijandael Encryption with a Pass Phrase and some Salt to encrypt the API key and logged in user name.

Comment: In hindsight, I realized that I can just set a new fedauth cookie by writing another session which would have been much more secure.